# Date from 2 wooden cube puzzle

Tags: calculation-puzzle, time

In an interview the interviewer asked me a question based on **date**.

Suppose in a office, at the manager's desk there are **2 wooden cubes** to show the date of month, every day the manager sets the cubes to show the current date of month.

> What will be the number at the surface of cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You need a zero, one and a two on both cubes, leaving six faces for 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 - seven numbers. The clever bit is that an upside 6 becomes 9, so any combo from here works.

Comment: yup ,it,s fine and we can find all date by using at first cube  0,1,2,3,4,5 and 0,1,2,6,7,8 at the second cube.